# Constrain View to square aspect ratio

Tags: flexbox, react-native

I'm playing with an iPhone app in react-native and I'd like a view to fill the screen in width and maintain a square aspect ratio.  So the height should equal the width.  I can't seem to find a way to achieve that.  The other option is to specify a specific width and height but I'm not seeing a way to query the device width from within react-native to allow me to do this.  Any pointers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope you are looking for this...

```
var Dimensions = require('Dimensions');
var device = Dimensions.get('window');


var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  squareBox: {
    width: device.width,
    height: device.width,
  }
);
```

Comment: Somehow I missed this, but it works!  I did find that assigning deviceWidth and deviceHeight as you have it results in "undefined" for me.  But doing var dims = Dimensions.get('window'); then looking at dims.width dims.height does work for me.  Thanks!

Comment: Better to simply do this in straight CSS using vw (viewport width) units with modern browsers.